# How to have multiple tables with the same schema in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to have multiple tables with the same schema, within the same database, using Entity Framework.

For example, if I have the classes below, and I login to the SQL Server database, I can only see a table that is named something like `dbo.Schema`.

Is there a way to have multiple tables with the same schema?

```
class Context1 : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Schema> table1 { get; set; }
}

class Context2 : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Schema> table2 { get; set; }
}

class Schema
{
    [Key]
    public int EntryId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes, create a new class for the other table. Are you trying to do some kind of table inheritance?

Comment: Please avoid to add tags into question title. Your question is already properly tagged

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to have multiple tables with the same schema?

You can either use [Data Annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/tables#data-annotations) or [Fluent API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/tables#fluent-api) to configure the table and schema name.

Suppose you have the following model:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Using Data Annotations, you could name it `blogging.blogs`:

```
[Table("blogs", Schema = "blogging")]
public class Blog
{
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public string Url { get; set; }
}
```

Using Fluent API, you can override `OnModelCreating` method to name it `blogging.blogs`:

```
class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Blog> Blogs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>()
            .ToTable("blogs", schema: "blogging");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simple do like this with multiple tables.

```
public partial class AdventureWorksEntities : DbContext
{
    public AdventureWorksEntities()
        : base("name=AdventureWorksEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AddressType> AddressTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ContactType> ContactTypes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CountryRegion> CountryRegions { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<StateProvince> StateProvinces { get; set; }
}
```

in this code we can add more table from same database. There is no need to create another class and inherit DbContext.
or you can do Add Item into project-> New Item->Data->ADO.NET Entity Data Model.
This will generate same code with your selected tables.

Thanks